# Azure DataGateway not showing as available for single user in Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, data-gateway

We have recently installed a Shared Data Gateway, however a single user is not able to see the Data Gateway within Logic Apps. When they search for Data Gateways (in the file system - create a file card) the dropdown is blank and lets them know there are no Data Gateways to select.The exact error message sees is "No Gateways found". I went to admin.powerplatform and added the user as a connection creator, however the user still is unable to see the data gateway. If I access the users Logic App, I am able to add the Data Gateway with no issue. The user is working in the same region as the shared Data Gateway.

I have tried to remove and re-add the users account from admin.powerplatform.com, however there has been no change. Is there somewhere else that Data Gateway access is managed? Does the user need access granted on a another resource, or is there a role that could be stopping him from adding the Datagateway? The user has the role Logic App contributor and is able to manage the logic app with no issue.

Comment: did you tried adding the user as a gateway administrator? Refer this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install.

Answer (score 0):

**AFAIK** generally this type of **No Gateways found** error occurs when user don't have appropriate role/permissions and the user is outside of your organization.

- As mentioned you already added user as a connection creator so once try to add the user as a [gateway administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection#frequently-asked-questions).
- once refer this [document](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Multiple-gateways-in-one-account/td-p/206337) as per this document one of the reasons would be different organization. Users inside the same organization can only access the on-premises data gateway. This means you cannot share your data gateway with your users who are outside of your corporation.

If still you are unable to resolve, you may need to contact [Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us) for further assistance.